# Schema.org for service based businesses without an address

Tags: schema.org

I have a service based business with no physical customer facing address. I can't seem to wrap my head around implementing a schema markup for a business like this but I'm sure I'm not the only one in such a position.

I've read that localbusiness is a local business (which we are) but it requires an address, I'd prefer not to display my address publicly, but that ship has already sailed for the most part. I know service falls under a localbusiness so I don't think that helps either.

Did I miss something?

Comment: What do you mean with "requires"? Schema.org itself doesn’t require you to provide any properties. If you mean Google: they require it for getting one of their rich results; if you don’t want to provide it, you can’t get the rich result in Google Search -- but nothing else happens.

Comment: I guess the purpose here is the try and build up my business in the local stack. I've been at the top before but not in a year or so. I see other businesses in my industry appear there and schema was one of the methods I read helps. What I'm getting at is, what is the correct way of writing schema for a business that doesn't accept customers at a physical location?

Comment: areaServed is a good way to indicate your service areas. I'm testing adding an address that excludes the street part.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath have you come to any conclusion about putting an address without the street part?

Comment: @dj50 nothing really. I'm not in an environment where I can compare with or without. Adding as much information as possible can't harm.

Answer (score 2):

The [`address`](https://schema.org/address) property does not imply that it’s a  customer-facing address.

The [`publicAccess`](https://schema.org/publicAccess) property allows to specify whether or not the `LocalBusiness` allows visitors:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress"
  },
  "publicAccess": false
}
```

That said, Schema.org doesn’t require any property. It’s perfectly fine to have a `LocalBusiness` without `address`. Certain data consumers might require certain properties for certain features; their documentation hopefully makes clear how they interpret the properties (e.g., if they require `address` and understand it to be a customer-facing address, the feature they offer is probably not intended for your case anyway; and they should ideally change their understanding of it, because there will be many addresses that aren’t intended to be visited by customers).